# Extracting ordered sub sequence from list

Tags: python, list, sequence

I am trying to extract **ORDERED** sequence. For example,

```
a = [2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 8, 5, 9]
b = [3, 8, 9, 4, 10, 11, 5]
c = [3,4,5]
```

`c` must hold values common to `a` and `b` where `[3,4,5]` appear in an order, `[8,9]` must not appear because it comes between `[3,4]` in `a` and between `[4,5]` in `b`

Another example as follows:

```
a = [2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
b = [2, 8, 3, 9, 10, 11]
c = [2,3,9,10]
```

I tried the following code:

```
a = [2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 8, 5, 9]
b = [3, 8, 9, 4, 10, 11, 5]

for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if i==j:
            print i
            break
```

I get the **WRONG** results as follows:

```
3
4
8
5
9
```

How do I avoid getting such an output? Also is there a pythonic way to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `tempval` and store the context. This can be done using the `enumerate` builtin function. Now using slices you will get the output as expected.

```
a = [2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 8, 5, 9]
b = [3, 8, 9, 4, 10, 11, 5]

tempval = 0
for i in a:
    for ind,j in enumerate(b[tempval:]):
        if i==j:
            print i
            tempval = ind
```

Output is

```
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ekoji, To get the list in order, you can try the below code. Sort the elements in the list a, So you get them in order.

```
a = [2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 8, 5, 9]
b = [3, 8, 9, 4, 10, 11, 5]
a.sort()
# use your logic 
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if i == j:
            print ("i is : %s j is :%s"  % (i , j))
            if len(c) > 1:
               print c
               print ("validation : %s :%s" %( c[-1] , i-1))
               if  c[-1:] == [i-1]:
                   print "continue"
                   c.append(i)
               else:
                   print "do Nothing"
            else:
                c.append(i)
print c


Output : 
[3, 4]
validation : 4 :4
continue
[3, 4, 5]
validation : 5 :7
do Nothing
[3, 4, 5]
validation : 5 :8
do Nothing
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Yep, But the OP wants 3,4,5 not 3,4,5,8,9

Comment: @ Bhargav Rao got it

Comment: Yep, So that is why this doesn't answer the question :-)

Comment: @ Bhargav Rao: I made changes to the code, This should work